# spatio-temporal event prediction

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have data that has some features such as latitude, longitude, timestamp, and category of an event. So the data set only has the events that actually took place. The thing is, I am wondering if there are preferred models that can be used to predict the following cases:

- The place (latitude and longitude) of next event given the current timestamp.
- The high probable time that event could occur given the current place.
- The probability of an event taking place given both time and space data.